# OpenACC: External variable and declare directive

Tags: openacc

I'm dealing with the acceleration of this subroutine.

```
void PTC3D(double ****V, double ****U)
{
  int i,j,k, nv;
  static double **u, **v;

  if (u == NULL){
    u = ARRAY_2D(NMAX_POINT, NVAR, double);
    v = ARRAY_2D(NMAX_POINT, NVAR, double);
    #pragma acc enter data copyin(v[:NMAX_POINT][:NVAR], u[:NMAX_POINT][:NVAR])
  }

  #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) private(v[:NMAX_POINT][:NVAR], u[:NMAX_POINT][:NVAR])
  for (k = KBEG; k <= KEND; k++){
  for (j = JBEG; j <= JEND; j++){
    #pragma acc loop collapse(2)
    for (i = IBEG; i <= IEND; i++){
      for (nv = 0; nv < NVAR; nv++) v[i][nv] = V[nv][k][j][i];
    }
    PTC (v, u, IBEG, IEND);
    #pragma acc loop collapse(2)
    for (i = IBEG; i <= IEND; i++){
      for (nv = 0; nv < NVAR; nv++) U[k][j][i][nv] = u[i][nv];
    }

  }}
}
```

I marked PTC with `#pragma acc routine vector` but inside of it I use an external variable `gamma` and hence the compiler generates: `External and Static variables are not supported in acc routine`.

I read that an alternative to passing gamma as function argument is the use of `#pragma acc declare`. I've no idea how it works.

I tried with `#pragma acc declare copyin(gamma)` at the beginning of the application, because gamma is defined at the beginning and never changed, but I get some error regarding the scope.
I'd need gamma on the device and to use it on every subroutine.

Comment: Where is gamma declared? Is it in a header file? Typically when I've used declare it's been declared in a header and I put the declare directive there so that the information about its availability on the device is visible everywhere.

Comment: @jefflarkin I tried with `extern double g_gamma;\ #pragma acc declare create(g_gamma)` in the header file but I get: **NVC++-S-0000-Internal compiler error. BAD sptr in var_refsym**

Comment: Looks similar to a known issue when putting "static" variables in "declare create" directive.  We have fix in place for upcoming the 20.11 release.  Though, if you could post a complete minimal reproducing example, I can double check that this is fixed as well.  As a work around, you might try omitting the "extern" keyword.

Comment: @MatColgrove yes, omitting "extern" works fine using `#pragma acc declare create(gamma)`